# better than Hölder leads to regularity?

Tags: integration, analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Consider a $L^2$-function $f:\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to[0,\infty)$ such that for any ball $B(x,r)\subset \Omega$, we have better than Hölder inequality :
$$
\int_{B(x,r/2)} |f| \leq \epsilon |B(x,r/2)|^\frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{B(x,r)} |f|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}
$$
for some $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. What can we say about the regularity of $f$ ? Is there an $\epsilon>0$ (depending only on the dimension or the domain) such that every fonction satisfying these inequalities is continuous or anything better than just $L^2$ ?
I have noticed that if we forget the $1/2$, and if we choose $x$ as a lebesgue point of $f$ and $f^2$, then one can divide by $|B(x,r)|$ and pass to the limit $r\to 0$ to get that $f=0$.
But if we consider the $1/2$, then a lot of nonzero functions satisfy this kind inequality (for instance if $f$ is harmonic). But in order to prove regularity, all proofs that i have seen need to have the same exponent on both side of the inequality : something of the form
$$
\int_{B(x,r/2)} |f|^p \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{B(x,r)} |f|^p
$$
in order to iterate it and get an inequality of the form
$$ 
\sup_{B(x,r)\subset B(0,\rho)} \frac{1}{r^{n-p}} \int_{B(x,r)}|f|^p \leq C \rho^\alpha
$$
for some $C,\alpha >0$, which is a Morrey space. In the case where $f=\nabla u$ for some $u$, this gives the Hölder continuity of $u$.
The question is : without the same exponent, can we still conclude to some regularity better than $L^2$ ?

Comment: Have you tried checking, when $n = 1$, with the function $f(x) = |x|^{p}$ for $p \in (0,1)$? A quick back of the envelope seems to suggest that for $\epsilon > 1/\sqrt{2}$ the inequality is satisfied for all $p \in (0,1)$?

Comment: In the case $p>0$ $|x|^p$ is continuous and if $0>p>-1/2$ the inequality is still true but we don't have continuity anymore. I should have been more specific. My question is more about : is there an $\epsilon>0$ (as small as needed) independant of $f$ such that this inequality for any $f$ leads to some regularity ?

Comment: Your question asks about _Holder_ continuity, and not just continuity, right? In any case, if you have corrections/clarifications, please edit it into the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, my question is about any kind of regularity better than $L^2$.

Comment: Actually, if you are allowed to choose $\epsilon$: why doesn't your Lebesgue point argument work? You have $$ |B(x,r/2)|^{-1} \int _{B(x,r/2)} |f| \leq 2^{n/2} \epsilon \left( |B(x,r)|^{-1} \int_{B(x,r)} |f|^2 \right)^{1/2} $$ On the RHS, inside the parentheses a.e. the mean converges to $|f(x)|^2$, and so you get a.e. $|f(x)| \leq 2^{n/2} \epsilon |f(x)|$, so for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small this guarantees $f$ vanishes a.e.